# What is the Fourier transform of the identity function?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

How to find the Fourier transform of $x \mapsto x$ using distribution $\delta$?

Since $FT(1)=\sqrt{2\pi} \delta(k)$ then $FT(x \cdot 1)=\sqrt{2\pi} i \delta'(k)$

But also since $1=d/dx (x)$ then $FT(x)=FT(1)/(ik)=\delta(k)/(ik)$

Are both of these correct?

Comment: You are not really allowed to write $\delta(k)/k$ in distribution theory, but the best interpretation if this expressions is $-\delta'(k)$.

Comment: Your first derivation is correct.

Comment: Your second derivation lacks a term $C \, \delta(k)$:
$$\sqrt{2\pi} \, \delta(k) = FT(1) = FT(\frac{d}{dx}x) = ik \, FT(x)$$
if and only if
$$-\sqrt{2\pi} \, \delta'(k) + C \, \delta(k) = i \, FT(x).$$